# u32 to ASCII Bytes without String Rust

Tags: rust, byte

i want to convert u32 into ASCII bytes.

```
input: 1u32
output [49]
```

This was my try, but its empty with 0u32 and also using Vec, i would prefer ArrayVec but how do i know the size of the number. Is there any simple way to do this , without using any dynamic allocations?

```
let mut num = 1u32;
let base = 10u32;
let mut a: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
while num != 0 {
    let chars = char::from_digit(num % base,10u32).unwrap();
     a.push(chars);
    num /= base;
}
 let mut vec_of_u8s: Vec<u8> = a.iter().map(|c| *c as u8).collect();
 vec_of_u8s.reverse();
 println!("{:?}",vec_of_u8s)
```

Comment: Is your input always between 0 and 9?

Comment: No, its from u32 min to u32 max

Comment: So… you want `format!("{num}").into_bytes()`, but for `ArrayVec`?

Comment: Yes i want to use ArrayVec instead of Array. But how do i get the lenght of the array? Also i need to consider zero is giving me Empty array

Comment: The amount of decimal digits in a number `n` is given by `ceil(log10(n))`. But unless `n` is constant, you can't get that number as a constant and thus not get an `ArrayVec` with the specified capacity unless you always use capacity 10 which is what `u32::MAX` would require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `write!` macro and `ArrayVec` with the capacity set to 10 (the maximum digits of a `u32`):

```
use std::io::Write;
use arrayvec::ArrayVec; // 0.7.2

fn main() {
    let input = 1u32;
    let mut buffer = ArrayVec::<u8, 10>::new();
    write!(buffer, "{}", input).unwrap();
    dbg!(buffer);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:10] buffer = [
    49,
]
```

Comment: no method named `write_fmt` found for struct `ArrayVec<u8, 10_usize>` in the current scope
method not found in `ArrayVec<u8, 10_usize>`

Comment: did you include the first import? `use std::io::Write;`

Comment: i did, still have this error. Cannot figure out why

Comment: not sure what to tell you then, it works on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdc3b5a6bfd0b4e726ec5d6b6d283518). Perhaps you're using an older version? Perhaps you're in a nested module so your import isn't in the right place?